# Proof of continuous function

Tags: general-topology

How I get the open sets of $\mathbb{R}_s$ to proof the follow exercise?

(a) Proof that identity function $id : \mathbb{R}_s \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ , where $\mathbb{R}_s$ is Sorgenfrey line, is continuous function.

How i can solve this exercises?

(b) Let $X$, $Y$ topological spaces and $f : X \rightarrow Y$.

Proof that if f is continuous function so , every $x \in X$ e every sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in X with $x_n \rightarrow^{n\rightarrow\infty} x$ then $f(x_n) \rightarrow^{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$.

(c) Proof that the reciprocal is valid if X is first countable.

Comment: You can prove that a function $f: X\to Y$ is continuous by proving that for every open set $O\subset Y$, the set $f^{-1}(O)$ is open. (i.e., you do it following the **definition** of continuity).

Comment: $[x,x + \epsilon[$ is not open set in real line.

Comment: Also, what you asked are three questions. I suggest you ask them one at a time, otherwise it will be hard to keep track of the answers.

Comment: Sure, but $[x, x+\epsilon[$ is also **not** the preimage of an open set, so that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a- The Sorgenfrey line is the set $\Bbb{R}$ with the topology whose base are the semi open intervals $[a,b[,\,\,a,b\in\Bbb{R}$. This means any open set of the Sorgenfrey line is constructed by finite intersection and union of elements of the base. Now the usual topology has the open intervals $]a,b[,\,\,a,b\in\Bbb{R}$ as a base. Keeping in mind that

$$]a,b[=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [a+{1\over n},b[$$

one sees that any open set of the usual line is an open set of the Sorgenfrey line and so the inclusion is continuous.

Comment: You have some ideas to solve items (b) and (c) ?